# C GTK - ProgressBar not acting as expected

Tags: c, gtk, progress-bar, packing

I'm trying to to show the current percentage of the progressbar inside the progressbar, which should be possible using GTK, however when I set the text value it shows above the progressbar instead of inside of it?

When `gtk_progress_bar_set_show_text(progressBar, TRUE); gtk_progress_bar_set_text(progressBar, NULL);` is run, it SHOULD show the current fraction of the progress bar inside the progressbar, however mine is showing above for some reason?

Should look like this:

[image]

Instead, it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    workingSetProgressBar = gtk_progress_bar_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(workingSetProgressBar, 240, -1);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(window_fixed), workingSetProgressBar, 372, 130);
    gtk_progress_bar_set_show_text(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(workingSetProgressBar), TRUE);
    gtk_progress_bar_set_text(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(workingSetProgressBar), NULL);
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(workingSetProgressBar), 0.5);
```

I have tried increasing the height of the bar in CSS, but the text still does not show within the bar, only on top of it, even when the bar is far taller than the text. The image shows when no CSS is active.

Anyone have any idea where I may be going wrong? Thanks

Comment: I believe that's just how progress bars look on Ubuntu. Try a different theme.

Comment: One way to fix this is [Something like I did here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVotiGnpwXQXNMHcGKr144z6).